# Endpoint MAC address change detection

Tags: switching, mac-address, arp, stacking

A question regarding a host behavior when gateway mac address has changed (although it deals with Windows, I think it's the best forum).

Assuming a windows host sending trafic to a destination IP, windows use the ARP table to send the trafic to the gateway MAC address. Assuming this gateway MAC address change (stack failover without persistent MAC address enabled, or other situations), how windows detect the MAC address change ? And how much time this detection take ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A host (Windows or any other) tries to keep its ARP table accurate by as many means as it can.  Normally there is a timeout for the cache entry and it's just discarded after a period since it had confirmation of this address (typically in the 60 to 1500 second range) -- but this is just to deal with the worst case scenario.  It also will update it more swiftly under many other conditions, in particular any incoming packet from that other host.

In the case you describe, a PC and a router, if the router suddenly changes ethernet address in mid-traffic, there are typically a number of TCP connections communicating.  One of them is likely to be a packet from the router, with the new ethernet address, to the PC.  At this point the PC udpates its cache, and starts the timer.  If the next packet is outgoing, the PC can invalidate its cache entry when it does a TCP retry, and perform normal ARP request.  (Whether a given OS does this is a topic for elsewhere.)  If the outgoing traffic is send-only (perhaps syslog over UDP) and there really is nothing coming from the router, then the PC won't know anything about the change, and will expire this cache entry after timeout since we last heard from the router -- which would have been the last ARP reply.

The normal case is that when any host changes ethernet (or IP) address, it sends ARP announcement packets to tell all the other hosts of the new details.

The worst case situation is that the PC keeps sending something to the old ethernet address until the cache times out, then issues a new ARP request and packet delivery resumes.

The ARP [RFC 826](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc826) is really a recommended read.  The address conflict [RFC 5227](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5227) covers a lot of good casees too.

Just for a postscript, it's terribly rare for routers to change their MAC addresses except if a) it's actually a different router, or b) there's some reconfiguration of some kind.  To solve the single-point-of-failure problem for hosts without good routing protocols, hot-standby router protocol and similar provide methods for an ethernet address to be shared by several routers.  (HSRP [RFC 2281](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2281), VRRP [RFC 5798](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5798)).

Answer (score 4):

Entries in the ARP table have a limited lifetime.

When they are outdated, the ARP process remove them from the table and the next time it needs to communicate with the associated IP address, it will perform an ARP request to find out the MAC address for this IP address -being it the same or a new one.

Also this entry is *not* refreshed when used, so it will always be discarded after the lifetime value, regardless of traffic.

So if any MAC address change, communication with the corresponding host  will fail until the ARP entry expires and the APR table is updated.

In case of a change a gratuitous arp *may* be sent to inform the hosts of the change, but this is device dependent.

Comment: Assuming we have a continue Layer 3 communication (application send data to destination every 5 seconds), as result the ARP table is permanently used and we have no ARP entry timeout, because continually used. In this case, how the host detect that the entry is bad ?

Comment: The entry lifetime is NOT refreshed when communication occur.